# Is there an assertDatabaseHas wildcard 'like' compare clause similar to Eloquent's 'like', (i.e. '%' . . '%')

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

I am running laravel dusk tests.

I am trying to determine whether the database has a record which contains a string.

Eloquent has a wildcard where clause that performs this activity.

i.e. `'like', '%' . $stringToSearch . '%'`

I am trying to find a syntax that performs the same comparison with `assertDatabaseHas` in my dusk browser tests.

Standard where query...

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('tableName',['TableField' => 'stringToFind']);
```

Query i would like to think exists...

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('tableName',['TableField' => 'like', '%' . $stringToSearch . '%']);
```

Comment: What is the name of the database?

Comment: i'm persisting to a mySql database

Comment: Regolith, thanks for editing the code: tried to but wasn't sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The way the `assertDatabaseHas()` function works is that the 2nd argument  `['TableField' => 'stringToFind']` is passed to an Illuminate QueryBuilder's `->where()` function so you end up in

```
->where(['TableField' => 'stringToFind'])
```

Because of this you can do the following:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('tableName',['TableField', 'LIKE', "%{$stringToSearch}%"]);
```

and achieve what you want

Comment: This worked for me and should be the accepted answer.